# GeoServer REST API get bounding box

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, wms

Will it be possible to get Bounding Box of uploading shapefile or geotiff?

I can able to upload shapefile and geotiff but not getting bounding box information. I am loading this shapefile and geotiff through WMS layer in Leaflet, and want to center map with layer. I want bounding to center map to geotiff and shapefile.

Answer (score 2):

The information is not available via the REST API, but once uploaded you'll find the layer in the WMS capabilities document, and there you can get its bounds.

Comment: Do you have any working example that have implemented this type of feature in leaflet map?

Comment: Sorry no, I'm a server side developer only.